# Linq call a function only once in one statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm quite new to Linq. I have something like this:

```
dict = fullGatewayResponse.
Split(',').ToDictionary(key => key.Split('=')[0], value => value.Split('=')[1])
```

This works fine but for obvious reasons I don't want the split() method to be called twice.
How can I do that ?

*Thanks for all your responses :), but I can only choose one.*

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the string fullGatewayResponse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert each item to an array before `ToDictionary` by using `Select`:

```
dict = fullGatewayResponse.Split(',')
                          .Select(item => item.Split('='))
                          .ToDictionary(keySelector:     parts => parts[0],
                                        elementSelector: parts => parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
dict = (from item in fullGatetayResponse.Split(',')
        let pair = item.Split('=')
        select pair).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

or, if you want to keep the existence of the array hidden:

```
dict = (from item in fullGatetayResponse.Split(',')
        let pair = item.Split('=')
        select new{Key=pair[0],Value=pair[1]).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: one of the few spots where I prefer query syntax

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
dict = fullGatewayResponse.Split(',')
       .Select(y => y.Split('='))
       .ToDictionary(y => y[0], x => x[1])
```

Comment: Please delete. Exact duplicate answer.

Comment: eh... Why did someone down vote? Please provide reason when down voting. Is there something wrong with the answer?

Comment: I downvoted, and reverted the vote. My first comment still goes. Exact duplicate answer.

Comment: but it is not exact duplicate now since he is using named arguments, and should you always delete duplicate answers. Isn't that just showing that the solution is correct?

Comment: It was pretty much exactly the same as yours. That answer was edited to make it clearer (not IMO, but anyways).

Answer (score 0):

This will work but I don't think there is any point in saving a split operation

```
var dict = fullGatewayResponse.Split(',')
                .Select(i=>i.Split('='))
                .ToDictionary(key=>key[0],value=>value[1]);
```

Comment: Sorry, till the time I was typing this, many have answered the same.